# Is it possible to set password for access of docker image while using docker exec commmand?

Tags: docker, security, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a project , whose files I want to keep secure inside docker image and I should be able to change things whenever required , so I want something like password based access so that no one can see project file and I can change them whenever required.

I am using multiple images through docker-compose , I have tried setting password for user but it will allow anyhow to get inside docker container without password also , Kindly suggest a way.

Comment: Not sure you can 'secure' the content of an image from anyone who has access to the image itself. So you could secure the registry to prevent that - but that may not be feasible and could make working with images hard. Alternatively, perhaps do not put the secure content inside the image, just mount it into the container at runtime? It is probably easier to secure access to the clusters/pods/containers preventing access to running containers and their content.

Comment: The above is good advice, one thing I'll add is if you need to have the content in the image you could encrypt it and then just mount/env variable a secret into the image to decrypt before using

Comment: There's no way to add a password for this.  Anyone who can run any `docker` command at all can very easily extract the contents of the image (whether via `docker exec`, `docker run`, or `docker cp`) and for that matter can very easily root the whole host (and read the files directly out of `/var/lib/docker`).